# C pointer symbol * used after a variable, not before

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning C language and I bumped into a line that is like the following one:

```
void myControl(const myInput*, myOutput*, myRuntime*, const myConfig*);
```

what does the * symbol mean after the variables?

I looked for 'C language * meaning' in the internet but I always find * as the symbol for the pointers that is placed before and not after a variable name.

Comment: If those aren't actually `typedef`d types then this is invalid C code

Comment: those are type names, not variable names. The arguments to that function are just not given a name in that declaration

Comment: Okay, I actually found that they are typedef types

`typedef struct myInput {

    myMode mode;

    float x;
    float y;

    float xz;
    float yz;
    
    float ABC1;
    float ABC2;
    float ABC3;

 float thRef;
    float psiRef;

    uint32_t t;
    
} myInput;`

Comment: Since this is a function prototype *declaration* (not a definition), the parameters don't need names.  That is, instead of `void(int a, int b, char *p, int *q)`, you can just say `void(int, int, char *, int *)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
void myControl(const myInput*, myOutput*, myRuntime*, const myConfig*);
```

- `myControl` is a function that takes 4 parameters.
- The function does not return a value.

Each of the parameters is a pointer to a type (presumably a structure). Some of the structures are `const` (unchangable).  Some of the structures can be changed.

The full function prototype in the conventional form with the parameter  names would look like:

```
void myControl(const myInput* inputData, myOutput* outputData, myRuntime* runTimeInfo, const myConfig* configuration);
```

- parameter `inputData` is a pointer to a structure of type `myInput`.
  It cannot be changed.
- parameter `outputData` is a pointer to a structure of type `myOutput`.
  It can be changed.
- parameter `runTimeInfo` is a pointer to a structure of type `myRuntime`.
  It can be changed.
- parameter `configuration` is a pointer to a structure of type `myConfig`.
  It cannot be changed.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question, which is asking what the `*` symbol means.

Comment: The last 4 bullet points answer that question: * makes the variable a pointer to the type.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
void myControl(const myInput*, myOutput*, myRuntime*, const myConfig*);
```

is a [function declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration).

Until C23, one of the key syntactical differences between a *function declaration* and a [function definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition), is that in a function declaration the *identifier* (what you refer to as the *"variable name"*) of each parameter in the parameter list is optional.

On the other hand, the identifier of each parameter is required in a function definition:

```
void myControl(const myInput* input, myOutput* ouput,
        myRuntime* rt, const myConfig* config)
{
    /* use the arguments, etc. */
    (void) input;
    (void) output;
    (void) rt;
    (void) config;
}
```

*(C23 will introduce [unnamed parameters in function definitions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/23) to the language.)*

What you see in the example are simply the types that form the function's *signature*, where each parameter is a [pointer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer) as indicated by the `*` symbol.

Comment: @TylerH The `*` indicates a pointer type, as addressed by the final statement in my answer. Please explain wherein your confusion lies.

Comment: "*The `*` indicates a pointer type*" is the critical part that answers OP's question, and wasn't in the answer.